# Solving namespace issue when consuming remote webservice in .net 4.5

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, namespaces

I'm trying to consume a web service provided by our membership database service (iMIS).

### Here's an example using the WSDL on their website.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.atsol.org/webservices_demo/wscontacts.asmx/");
var c = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Username", "myname"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Password", "mypassword"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UpdateLoggedInDate", "false")
});
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
LoginResultsWithData r = response.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<LoginResultsWithData>().Result;
```

It works fine however when it gets to the last line and attempts to deserialize the XML into a "LoginResultsWithData" object it runs into an error on the name space.

> Error in line 1 position 163. Expecting element 'LoginResultsWithData' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/myProjectName.iMISContactService'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'LoginResultsWithData', namespace 'http://www.atsol.org/wsContacts/'.

### This is the response from the webservice

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2013 19:48:59 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1202

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LoginResultsWithData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.atsol.org/wsContacts/">
  <ResultCode>#</ResultCode>
  <ResultMessage>Succeeded</ResultMessage>
  <ID>####</ID>
  <InstituteContactId>####</InstituteContactId>
  <IsMember>false</IsMember>
  <IsInstitute>false</IsInstitute>
  <CustomerTypeCode>S</CustomerTypeCode>
  <BillingCategory />
  <ContactStatusCode>A</ContactStatusCode>
  <PaidThruDate>2099-12-31T00:00:00</PaidThruDate>
  <FullName>My Name</FullName>
  <FirstName>My</FirstName>
  <LastName>Name</LastName>
  <Informal>My</Informal>
  <Roles />
  <IMISCookies>
    <IMISCookie>
      <CookieName>ASP.NET_SessionId</CookieName>
      <CookieValue>io0um25qmae35wiogsjgwrsq</CookieValue>
    </IMISCookie>
    <IMISCookie>
      <CookieName>Login</CookieName>
      <CookieValue>34E1A645EB3F4AE693EDEE665D2328264C7F064B366DE16286DF83E6D79AF7663294E1275DA22703506F3E8E3F89D02C27DAB30F2D6A4A43A3AF1A6D0DCD1A2AFDFD18073E6187111430228892A9C7EC</CookieValue>
    </IMISCookie>
  </IMISCookies>
</LoginResultsWithData>
```

And before you ask, no I can't mess with the web-service. 
Help?!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the service provider has updated their wsdl and the client machinery needs a regen as the response posted appears to be consistent with the types specified in the WSDL at http://www.atsol.org/webservices_demo/wscontacts.asmx?WSDL

Based on the error message, somewhere in the web service client machinery the incorrect namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/myProjectName.iMISContactService' has been associated with the response element 'LoginResultsWithData'.

The WSDL and the posted response indicate a LoginResultsWithData associated with namespace 'http://www.atsol.org/wsContacts/' (in the wsdl:types section, this is covered by the targetNamespace="http://www.atsol.org/wsContacts/" attribute of the schema element; in the response, this is indicated with the attribute xmlns="http://www.atsol.org/wsContacts/" of the LoginResultsWithData element).